# python : How can I replace complex number to -1?

Tags: python, numpy

I found out isinstance method which can recognize whether the number is complex or not.
and my data is looks like this.

```
[[ 2.48983949+0.j          0.51935128+0.j          0.50851186+0.j
   0.49747311+0.j          0.48621321+0.j          0.47549854+0.j
   0.32583775+0.j          0.32263812+0.j          0.31966799+0.j
   0.31415193+0.j          0.31590046+0.j          0.31224772+0.j
   0.30953578+0.j        ]
 [ 2.78263801+0.j          0.47996998+0.j          0.46950057+0.j
   0.45938939+0.j          0.44934962+0.j          0.43981685+0.j
   0.30778303+0.j          0.30533936+0.j          0.30283312+0.j
   0.30045755+0.j          0.29776178+0.j          0.29601522+0.j
   0.29394237+0.j        ]
 [ 0.00000000+0.86404032j  0.44030961+0.j          0.43096323+0.j
   0.42117570+0.j          0.41239587+0.j          0.40406585+0.j
   0.29059586+0.j          0.28840336+0.j          0.28632998+0.j
   0.28435365+0.j          0.28251060+0.j          0.28053645+0.j
   0.27894779+0.j        ]]
```

So the data is 2-dimensional numpy array.

And I want to replace imaginary number to -1. How could I do this?

Comment: Iterate, check, replace.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you want to happen to a complex number like `2+4j`? Does it become `-1`, `-2` or `-4`?

Comment: Thanks. But I am looking for more efficient way

Comment: I want to make that every complex number became -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you could do something like this:

```
>>> arr = np.array([[1,2+3j,4+5j],[6+7j,8,9],[10+11j,12,13+14j]])
>>> arr
array([[  1. +0.j,   2. +3.j,   4. +5.j],
       [  6. +7.j,   8. +0.j,   9. +0.j],
       [ 10.+11.j,  12. +0.j,  13.+14.j]])
>>> arr[abs(arr.imag) > 0] = -1
>>> arr
array([[  1.+0.j,  -1.+0.j,  -1.+0.j],
       [ -1.+0.j,   8.+0.j,   9.+0.j],
       [ -1.+0.j,  12.+0.j,  -1.+0.j]])
```

And then (since by construction we have all imaginary parts being zero) we could work with only the real components if we wanted:

```
>>> arr.real
array([[  1.,  -1.,  -1.],
       [ -1.,   8.,   9.],
       [ -1.,  12.,  -1.]])
```

(Update: as noted by Floris, `arr.imag != 0` would be even better than `abs(arr.imag) > 0`.  It'd be both simpler and faster, though both will work.)

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to work with numpy arrays. Lets say you have the array:

```
In [106]: y
Out[106]:
array([[ 1.+0.j,  2.+0.j,  1.+0.j],
       [ 1.+0.j,  2.+0.j,  1.+0.j],
       [ 2.+3.j,  2.+0.j,  3.+0.j]])
```

Then,

```
In [107]: y.imag > 0
Out[107]:
array([[False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

You can then use this to replace things with one:

```
In [108]: y[y.imag > 0] = -1

In [109]: y
Out[109]:
array([[ 1.+0.j,  2.+0.j,  1.+0.j],
       [ 1.+0.j,  2.+0.j,  1.+0.j],
       [-1.+0.j,  2.+0.j,  3.+0.j]])
```

Comment: You will want "not equal to zero" not "greater than zero" but otherwise I agree with this approach.

Comment: Thanks Floris. I missed that one. My bad!

Comment: `y[abs(y.imag) > 0] = -1`